# Move Pods as part of a deployment within a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I am creating an autonomous rescheduler that is capable of rescheduling Pods on the go based on resource usage, network metrics and so on. My Kubernetes cluster currently only has 5 deployments as a test setup each with only a single instance of a Pod (replicas: 1). I am able to generate a new scheduling in my system and apply that to the cluster by executing the following patch;

```
kubectl patch deployment fake-microservice-1 -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"spec\":{\"nodeSelector\":{\"kubernetes.io/hostname\":\"node1\"}}}}}"
```

This patch successfully moves the Pod in the `fake-microservice-1` deployment to `node1`.

The next thing I want to implement is, in case there are multiple replicas of a Pod in a deployment, that I am able to move each individual Pod within the deployment to a specific node. For example, assume the `fake-microservice-1` deployment to have 2 replicas (2 Pods). How can I, for example, move one of the Pods to `node1` and the other to `node4`.

I have tried to patch a single Pod's `nodeAffinity` but this isn't possible because Kubernetes doesn't allow updates to this value when a Pod is running.

Is there a way to move individual Pods within a deployment to a specific node, either by patching some values, adding labels or through other means?

Not that it matters too much but all of this is being developed in Go.

Comment: you are right on using nodeaffinity however i have doubt on `because Kubernetes doesn't allow updates to this value when a Pod is running` you can use `requiredDuringSchedulingRequiredDuringExecution`

Comment: what if you will patch the deployment with affinity and anti affinity while pod running it will creat the new pods at that time maybe it will consider the rule of affinity which we added using the patch. adding the affinity and anti-affinity might be helpful together.

Comment: I have tried the following command; `kubectl patch pod fake-microservice-1-75f65b9dcf-cv4h7 -p "{\"spec\":{\"affinity\":{\"nodeAffinity\":{\"requiredDuringSchedulingRequiredDuringExecution\":{\"nodeSelectorTerms\":[{\"matchExpressions\":[{\"key\":\"kubernetes.io/hostname\",\"operator\":\"In\",\"values\":[\"node3\"]}]}]}}}}}"` but I get `The Pod "fake-microservice-1-75f65b9dcf-cv4h7" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than ...`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you are managing the pod with `kind:deployment`  or as pod?

Comment: As `kind: deployment`. But I would like to be able to move individual Pods within the deployment to a specific node.

Comment: I also just found out that `requiredDuringSchedulingRequiredDuringExecution ` isn't implemented yet https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/96149. Would there be another way?

Comment: patching single pod i dont think will work as replicas managed by deployment so.